# Hosting WCF service on IIS7.5

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5

i am new to wcf. i have created and hosted simple wcf service on iis 7.5 using tutorial from http://debugmode.net/2010/09/07/walkthrough-on-creating-wcf-4-0-service-and-hosting-in-iis-7-5/

all goes fine until i tried to consume this service. when i try to add service reference in my client it gives following error

> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://localhost:4567/Service1.svc?wsdl'. The WSDL document contains
>   links that could not be resolved. There was an error downloading
>   'http://localhost:4567/Service1.svc?xsd=xsd0'. The underlying
>   connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
>   Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host Metadata contains a
>   reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://localhost:4567/Service1.svc'. Content Type
>   application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service
>   http://localhost:4567/Service1.svc.  The client and service bindings
>   may be mismatched. The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot
>   process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml;
>   charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'. If
>   the service is defined in the current solution, try building the
>   solution and adding the service reference again.

web.config of my service contains

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

 <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
 </system.web>
 <system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>

         <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>

         <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
 </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: what is the wcf configuration on the client side?

Comment: there is no wcf configuration on client side. at client i m jux trying to add service reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a generic error usually caused by an exception being thrown by the service. Unfortunately, since `includeExceptionDetailInFaults` is set to false in your config, you do not see any soap exception details on your client consuming the service.

First, set `includeExceptionDetailInFaults = "true"` in your development environment so you may see any additional exception details. Next, try to use a browser and navigate directly to http://localhost:4567/Service1.svc to see if the generic service page is displayed. Then try to navigate to http://localhost:4567/Service1.svc?wsdl to see if the WSDL is appropriately displayed. Any errors being thrown by the service should be thrown to the browser in both situations. Hopefully, this helps lead you to the root cause of your problem. Please post any additional information you find if you still cannot figure out the problem. Good luck!

Comment: i have tried to access it in browser on both of ur described urls and it works fine in the browser. i have changed includeExceptionDetailInFaults to true in web.config. and republished service and tries to add reference in client but it gives exactly same error without extra detail.

Comment: Next step is to try to access the xsd throwing the error. Try navigating to http://localhost:4567/Service1.svc?xsd=xsd0 in your browser to see if any errors are thrown.