# Hosting WCF service on IIS7.5, receiving 404.0 error

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-7.5

I just received a new development laptop and now I can't get one of my WCF services running on the new laptop.

Windows 7 Enterprise

IIS 7.5.7600.16385

Windows Features Installed:

- Internet Information Services

  - Web Management Tools
  - IIS 6 Management Compatibility
  - IIS Management Console
  - IIS Management Scripts and Tools
  - IIS Management Service
- World Wide Web Services

  - Application Development Features (all sub-features)
  - Common HTTP Features

    - Default Document
    - Directory Browsing
    - HTTP Errors
    - HTTP Redirection
    - Static Content (all sub-features)
  - Health and Diagnostics (all sub-features)
  - Performance Features (all sub-features)
  - Security (all sub-features)
- Internet Information Services Hostable Web Core
- Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 (all sub-features)
- Windows Process Activation Service (all sub-features)

I dropped a simple "Hello World!" index.html file at the root of the WCF services application. I am able to serve that .html file. My services are under a sub-directory named "Hosts". I also dropped a simple index.html file under that sub-directory - I am able to serve that file as well. I cannot serve any of my .svc files though.

http://localhost/mywcfapplication/Hosts/IncidentService.svc

Anonymous Authentication -- "Application pool identity" is selected

The services are running in their own application pool. About the app pool:

- .NET Framework Version: v2.0
- Enable 32-bit applications: false
- Managed Pipeline Mode: Classic
- Identity: ApplicationPoolIdentity

I recently set these services up on a new Windows Server 2012 R2 web server in our test environment (old test server was decommissioned). On the server I had to give the app pool user permission to the directory in the file system (IIS_IUSRS\apppoolname), but my laptop doesn't seem to like this.

I'm receiving a 404.0 error when I attempt to browse to any of my .svc files under this application. IIS tells me the most likely causes are: •The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
•The URL contains a typographical error.
•A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.

I have checked and re-checked the URL, and I can serve the .html files. I verified that the .svc files do exist. I'm at a loss. What have I overlooked?

Research:

[IIS7.5 WCF Service - HTTP Error 401.3 (Even after adding IIS_IUSRS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054514/iis7-5-wcf-service-http-error-401-3-even-after-adding-iis-iusrs)

[Hosting WCF service on IIS7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401863/hosting-wcf-service-on-iis7-5)

[Windows 7 IIS7.5 and asp application Error HTTP 404.0 - Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329647/windows-7-iis7-5-and-asp-application-error-http-404-0-not-found)

**UPDATES:**

6/8/15 - I added `IIS AppPool\AppPoolName` to the IIS_IUSRS group. No change.

6/9/15 -

- I ran `servicemodelreg -i`. No change.
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752252(v=vs.90).aspx

  - Because I'm getting desperate, I ran `aspnet_regiis –i –enable` and then `"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\ServiceModelReg.exe" -r`
  - I also followed the steps listed "to verify that the svc file type is mapped correctly in IIS7.0"
- [HTTP 404 when accessing .svc file in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609377/http-404-when-accessing-svc-file-in-iis) -- "We had a similar problem, and the SVC handler was already correctly installed. Our problem was the ExtensionlessUrl handler processing requests before they reached the SVC handler. To check this - in Handler Mappings in IIS Manager at the web server level, view the list of handlers in order (it's an option on the right-hand side). If the various ExtensionlessUrl handlers appear above the SVC handlers, then repeatedly move them down until they're at the bottom."

  - I verified that the extensionless handlers were at the bottom.
- At the advice from yet another forum post I added a MIME type for .svc. No change.

6/15/2015 - 
 - Log file: [u_ex150615.log](http://1drv.ms/1dGCGSW)

Comment: Have you tried using the [ServiceModel Registration Tool (ServiceModelReg.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732012(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @Tim, no I hadn't tried ServiceModel Registration Tool.  I ran it just now. My service is still throwing a 404.0. And late yesterday afternoon I noticed that my WCF services on the test server aren't working either.  I can browse to them and the "You have created a service" page loads. But if I try to call a web method via an application I receive a 404.0 error. I've never had this much trouble deploying WCF services before.

Comment: Exactly the same issue here. Local dev IIS 7.5 and server IIS 6. Same behavior.

Comment: I don't know why this was a problem, but I had exactly the same scenario and fixed removing the address attribute from endpoint service tag. Seen here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/933aa090-63de-4913-98e4-1677e0c7ec95/can-browse-to-service-but-get-a-404-error-when-consuming?forum=wcf

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same issue and finally found a way through it.

The point is that `WCF` need a integrated pipeline to work properly. In `Windows 7's IIS 7.7` I solved the problem by setting the `Application Pool` to use `Integrated Pipeline` mode (it was in `Classic Mode`). But `Windows Server 2003's IIS 6` doesn't work with integrated pipeline, so `Microsoft .Net` uses `Web Services Extensions`, you could check at `IIS 6`, right above `Web Sites`. Ensure that the desired `.Net` version is allowed in `Web Services Extensions`. Than you need to register the `Service Model` extension.

Here´s what I did:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\ServiceModelReg.exe -i
```